# Does copy.deepcopy() automatically check the memo dict and use that object when it's present?

Tags: python, pyqt, copy, copy-paste, deep-copy

I'm writing a state machine editor so as you might imagine because of it's directed graph nature, and referencing of related objects in multiple places otherwise, there is a big need for the memo arg of `__deepcopy__`.  Do I need to check for existence of id's in the memo, or does python do that for me and return the memoized object *and skip* the call to my custom `__deepcopy__`?

I know I will find out soon, but thought I might add to the content of SO since it is an unasked question, and also that will rule out one thing when debugging if I know for sure from your comments.

I'm doing a deepcopy on my `QGraphicsObject` subclasses, `NodeObject,  ArrowObject, BaseObject, TextObject`, and a few other types.   Node objects might reference arrows and vice versa, as well as an editor class that holds a dict of objects and arrows.  You can copy an editor or you can copy objects within the editor, and also copy/paste them across editors.  Quite complex!

Digression: By the way, I have very beautifully behaving blocks & arrows.  So proud of them.

Comment: was the pyqt tag a mistake?

Comment: @ No, I'm using pyqt.  If there is any caveats because of that, it would be good to air them.  I'm copying `QGraphicsObject` subclasses.  So far, have successfully copied a `QGraphicsView/ QGraphicsScene`.

Comment: You should probably add that explicitly to the text of the question.

Comment: Not 100% sure yet, but I think it's auto-handled by copy.deepcopy, as I'm copying editors with graphs with loops already